# Require.js Module Path Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, requirejs, underscore.js

I don't understand why my view module (overlay.screen.view.js) require variables are undefined (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of undefined) when alerting. The paths appear to be correct but clearly something is screwed up. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is my directory structure:

```
www
 |-js
   |-app
     consumer.activity.js
     |-views
       overlay.screen.view.js
   |-test
   |-vendor
     |-backbone
     |-fastclick
     |-jquery
     |-sinon
     |-superslides
     |-underscore
```

Inside my consumer.activity.js file (essentially main.js):

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: '../../js',
    paths: {
        root: '..',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery.2.0.3.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'fastclick': {
            exports: 'FastClick'
        },
        'phonegap': {
            exports: 'phonegap'
        },
        'cordova': {
            exports: 'cordova'
        },
        'sinon': {
            exports: 'sinon'
        }
    }

});

define(function(require) {

    "use strict";

    var // core libraries
        phonegap                = require('root/phonegap'),
        $                       = require('jquery'),
        _                       = require('vendor/underscore/underscore-1.5.2-min'),
        Backbone                = require('vendor/backbone/backbone-1.1.0-min'),
        FastClick               = require('vendor/fastclick/fastclick-0.6.11-min'),
        appConfig               = require('app/lib/xcelarys.app'),
        ScreenOverlayView       = require('app/views/overlay.screen.view'),
        sinon,
        test,

        // $elements
        $body;

    try {
        // Bootstrap test framework/server
        if (xcelarys.app.environ() === 'DEV' && xcelarys.app.testMode() === 'ON') {
            sinon               = require('test/sinon');
            test                = require('test/xcelarys.test');
        }

        // Perform page config
        FastClick.attach(document.body);    // Make click events fast!

        $body = $('body');

        var screenOverlayView = new ScreenOverlayView( { el: $body } );
        screenOverlayView.render();
        screenOverlayView.show( window.outerHeight, window.outerWidth );
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

Here is the view module, overlay.screen.view.js:

```
define( function( require ) {

    "use strict";

    var  $               = require('jquery'),
         _               = require('../../vendor/underscore/underscore-1.5.2-min'),
         Backbone        = require('../../vendor/backbone/backbone-1.1.0-min'),
         tmpl            = require('text!app/tmpl/overlayscreen.html'),
         template        = _.template(tmpl);  // // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of undefined .

    alert($);
    alert(_);
    alert(Backbone);
    alert(template());

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        render: function() {

            this.$el.append(template());
            return this;

        },

        show: function( heightInPixels, widthInPixels ) {

            this.$('#overlayscreen').css('height', heightInPixels);
            this.$('#overlayscreen').css('width', widthInPixels);
            this.$('#overlayscreen').removeClass('hide');

        },

        hide: function() {

            this.$el.addClass('hide');

        }

    });

});
```

**Update**:

Seddass' post below lead me to the following solution. Essentially, I needed to update require.config() paths so that shims work as expected. Here is the code:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../../js',
    paths: {
        root: '..',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery.2.0.3.min',
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore/underscore-1.5.2-min',
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone/backbone-1.1.0-min',
        test: 'test'
    },

    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'fastclick': {
            exports: 'FastClick'
        },
        'phonegap': {
            exports: 'phonegap'
        },
        'cordova': {
            exports: 'cordova'
        },
        'sinon': {
            exports: 'sinon'
        }
    }
});

require([
    'root/phonegap',
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'vendor/fastclick/fastclick-0.6.11-min',
    'app/lib/xcelarys.app',

    // Views
    'app/views/overlay.screen.view',
    'app/views/global.header.1.view',

    // Models
    'app/models/global.header.1.models'
    ],
    function(
        phonegap,
        $,
        _,
        Backbone,
        FastClick,
        appConfig,
        ScreenOverlayView,
        GlobalHeader1,
        GlobalHeader1Model
    ) {
        "use strict";
        // code
    }
});
```

Now I can access libs in my module.

```
define( function( require ) {
    "use strict";
    var  $               = require('jquery'),
         _               = require('underscore'),
         Backbone        = require('backbone'),
         tmpl            = require('text!app/tmpl/overlayscreen.html'),
         template        = _.template(tmpl);

    alert('overlay.screen#jquery = ' + $);
    alert('overlay.screen#underscore = ' + _);
    alert('overlay.screen#backbone = ' + Backbone);
    alert('overlay.screen#template' + template());

    // Code here!
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your version of Underscore.js is not AMD enabled so you use shim in your config. 
But I believe that when calling

```
require('../../vendor/underscore/underscore-1.5.2-min');
```

your shim cant recognise that you are calling 'underscore' to enable the export of '_'.
Have you tried to set underscore in paths, in shim settings and later to require it with the same path?

In other words:

```
require.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        'underscore' : '../../vendor/underscore/underscore-1.5.2-min',
        ....
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore' : {
             exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

in your view (or in any AMD js file):

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by the time, it gets to exec

```
template        = _.template(tmpl);
```

underscorejs may not be fully loaded. There is where "Asynchronous" means in Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD). You need to restructure your code to something like below to make it work:

```
require(['underscore', 'text!app/tmpl/overlayscreen.html'], function (_, tmpl) {
    template        = _.template(tmpl);
    console.log (template);

});
```

You can also look at the example in [here](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette).

**Updated**

Simulated your situation using jsfiddle in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BN6Xc/39/).
Since you have all the modules defined in config object, you use the module names in your 'sugar' version like in the following, it should work.

```
var  $               = require('jquery'),
     _               = require('underscore'),
    Backbone         = require('backbone');
```

Comment: Thanks Ming. A few things: 1. I am familiar with the asynchronous nature of JS. 2. Above solution you provided doesn't work. 3. I use something called syntactic sugar ([link](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar)) which eliminates the verbosity of the dependency array (converted behind the scenes). 4. Still appears to be an issue with either path or loading in the overlay.screen.view.js file.

Comment: Provided a simulated solution using jsfiddle. Please let me know if that help your situation.